Who are the "we" in Colossians 1:27-28?
Colossians 1:27-28, Douay-Rheims 1899 American edition:

To whom God would make known the riches of the glory of this mystery among the Gentiles, which is Christ, in you the hope of glory. Whom we preach, admonishing every man, and teaching every man in all wisdom, that we may present every man perfect in Christ Jesus.

Who are the "we" in this passage?

Do you have a particular reason to suppose that "we" refers to someone other than Paul and Timothy, who pre-sign the letter in the first verses, addressing themselves to the Colossians?

Paul is the teacher, and because Timothy was not a coauthor but rather an amanuensis, the null hypothesis is that "we" semantically equals "I". Maybe he didn't want to sound self-centered.

Ah, I never read it that way. Since they both appeared in the same field, I thought they were co-authors of the letter.

@Fomalhaut There seems to be a deliberate distinction between the "we" you quote in Colossians 1:28 and immediately following "I" in Colossians 1:29: Wherein also I labour, striving according to his working which he worketh in me in power.  This happens elsewhere in the same chapter.

The epistle mentions a number of persons, all of whom could be included in the 'we'.
Paul himself, Timothy, Tychicus, Onesimus, Aristarchus, Marcus, Barnabas, Jesus (called Justus), Epaphras, Luke, Nymphas and Archippus.
Twelve in all ; a remarkable number, I suggest.
Apostolic, I would venture to mention.

Are all twelve names mentioned before this reference to "we"? And whether the specific number of proper names in the book is somehow special veers very near to, if not right into, speculation - do you have any sources that provide such a view?

Meyers answers this question in his comments about Col 1:28 and identifies the "we" -

Colossians 1:28. Christ was not proclaimed by all in the definite
character just expressed, namely, as “Christ among the Gentiles, the
hope of glory;” other teachers preached Him in a Judaistic form, as
Saviour of the Jews, amidst legal demands and with theosophic
speculation. Hence the emphasis with which not the simply epexegetic
ὅν (Erasmus and others), but the ἡμεῖς, which is otherwise
superfluous, is brought forward;[74] by which Paul has meant himself
along with Timothy and other like-minded preachers to the Gentiles
(we, on our part).

That the "we who proclaim Him" are identified, in part in the first verse of Col 1 -

Paul, an apostle of Christ Jesus by the will of God, and Timothy our
brother,

However, I am sure that "we" also includes any other preacher in Paul's time that proclaimed Christ according to the doctrine he explains in V24-27.

To whom God would make known the riches of the glory of this mystery among the Gentiles, which is Christ, in you the hope of glory. Whom we preach, admonishing every man, and teaching every man in all wisdom, that we may present every man perfect in Christ Jesus.
The hope of glory seems a direct reference to the holy spirit. Who as we see in first John 2,27 is the one who teaches men in all wisdom. The we in the last statement seems to be a reference to those who are filled with said teacher.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
